# How to edit or insert cell data using gdata-objectivec-client?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am able to fetch All the feeds, Worksheets and Cell data of a Google Spreadsheet using the GData Objective-C Client.

But I am stuck with adding/modifying cell data on a Google Spreadsheet using the GData Objective-C Client. *I used this* http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction#Batch_requests

If there is any code example, highly appreciated.

thanks in advanced.